# fadeToggle corresponding div with regex in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am displaying small content(id=showmore_ and with the forloop counter) (30 words) of the comment initially. I want to hide it and show all the content of id more_content_ of same loop counter.

HTML:

```
<div class="comment"> Comments ({{discuss.get_comments|length}}):
     {% for comment in discuss.get_comments %}
          <div id="showmore_{{ forloop.counter }}">
              {{ comment.commenter.get_full_name }} - {{ comment.body|truncatewords:30 }}...
                                <em>Read More</em>
          </div>
          <div id="more_content_{{ forloop.counter }}" style="display: none;">
                                {{ comment.body }}
          </div>
          <div>
                {% for subcomment in comment.get_subcomments %}
                    <div>{{ subcomment.body|truncatewords:30 }</div>
                {% endfor %}
          </div>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^="showmore_"]').click(function(){
         $('div[id^="more_content_"]').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

When I give same id to all( eg. showmore or more_content), every element gets hidden or shown.

What do I do?

Comment: Try giving classes instead of IDs. Ids are unique...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code example selects the clicked div using `this`. Then, it finds it's sibling with the correct id (using the jQuery `sibling` function), and toggles it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^="showmore_"]').click(function(){
        var moreContent = $(this).siblings('div[id^="more_content_"]');
        moreContent.fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="showmore_1">
    Show More 1
  </div>
  <div id="more_content_1">
    Content 1
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="showmore_2">
    Show More 2
  </div>
  <div id="more_content_2">
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was **perfect**. :D

Comment: @Khizir Mark the solution as accepted to show that the question has been answered.